# Use Same component multiple times failed. How can I get the thing done?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYFfQ.png)**Use Same component multiple times failed. How can I get the thing done?**

Why it's render only single element even though Multiple components Added.?

I use Todo Component multiple times in the Todos component, But it's give only just one element rendered.

> Todo.js File

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Todo extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <h3 className="text-dark text-center p-1 bg-light">
                <i className="fas fa-times-circle fa-sm float-left mr-1 text-danger"></i> Task {this.props.num}
                <input type="checkbox" className="mr-2 float-right"/>
            </h3>
        )
    }
}
```

> Todos.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Todo from "./Todo"

export default class Todos extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Todo num="1"></Todo>
                <Todo num="2"></Todo>
                <Todo num="3"></Todo>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[Output I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYFfQ.png)
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A1f6.png)

Comment: Please add the output html you are seeing.

Comment: your code is working fine, you can check here - 
https://codesandbox.io/s/9dho5

Comment: I added a screenshot of Expected and got Outputs.

"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  }